# Faster way to intersect arrays

Tags: algorithm, php

I need to intersect lots of arrays with each other. Those arrays are like:

```
$a = array(4 => true, 10 => true, 18 => true...);
$b = array(6 => true, 10 => true, 73 => true...);
$c = array(106 => true, 293 => true, 297 => true...);
```

In PHP there is a function `array_intersect_key`, which intersects keys; it works fine but it's not very efficient. There is also another function `array_intersect`, which intersects values, and is much slower than `array_intersect_key` because it's `O (n^2)` instead of `O (n)` (`array_intersect_key`).

The problem with `array_intersect_key` is that it does lots of pre computation before executing the intersection, like ordering the arrays, verifying data types... at **every call** but I don't need that because my arrays are already ordered and contain only numbers. So I came up with this function:

```
function array_intersect_key_custom($a,$b) {
    
    $intersection = array();
    
    foreach ($a as $chave1 => $valor1) {
    
        if (isset($b[$chave1])) {
        
            $intersection [$chave1] = true;
        
        }

    }
    
    return $intersection;

}
```

This function runs a little faster than any other alternative I came up, but it's still too slow. Is there any code optimization, mathematical operation, matrix operation... that I can do in order to make this code run faster?

Comment: Are you able to eliminate whole chunks of elements from your comparison arrays by using array_slice when the max key of your first array is exceeded by the comparison array? Or do the arrays have a good mix of high and low numbers that this will not likely deliver a benefit?

Comment: How do we know how to benchmark accurately without knowing how to set the volume and number of arrays?

Comment: Is this one of those times when you use `yield`?

Answer (score 2):

I tried hard but I couldn't find anything faster than the native `array_intersect_key`. It runs 30-50% faster than your function in my tests. Tried with PHP 7.0 and this array generator for test data:

```
function randomArr($size, $max) {
  $res = [];
  for ($i = 0 ; $i<$size; $i++) {
    $r = random_int(1, $max);
    if (!isset($res[$r])) {
      $res[$r] = true;
    }
    else {
      $i = $i-1;
    }
  }
  ksort($res);
  return $res;
}
```

Try with 10 Mio entries and `$max=100000000` and I'd be really surprised if your function was faster. Maybe the densitiy of your arrays plays a role?

However, I found one little optimization for your function: If you don't require the result to have the form `[3 => true, 7 => true, 23 => true, ...]`, but you can work with `[0 => 3, 1 => 7, 2 => 23, ...]` as well, it's a bit faster to just push the intersection keys onto the result array: `$intersection[] = $chave1;`. But this only saved me at most 10%.

Comment: thank you for your tests (I am running PHP 8 and maybe that's why my custom code runs faster than native `array_intersect_key`). Thank you for your suggestion on the second part of your answer, indeed assigning the results to values instead of keys is faster! Thank you. If no better answer come up in the next days, I will accept yours :)

Comment: Thank you for the well considered, if uncommented test data generator.